# Texstudio: modify size of line numbers

Tags: texstudio, line-numbering

With more than 1000 lines the line numbering in Texstudio 2.7.0 takes up a sizeable chunk of my display.

I already discovered that it's possible to disable the line numbers in `Options
-> Advanced Editor -> Appearance -> Line Numbers` in [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839/thread/60e7239d/).

But what i'd really like would be to make the number or column smaller (for exampling when i'm working in the sub 1000 line range it could be one character smaller).

Is there a way to make the line numbering smaller? (for example via fontsize?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make what you want is to modify the source code. The following patch should do what you want. Maybe you will want to change `4` in  `f.setPointSize(f.pointSize()-4)` to have a bigger or smaller font size for line numbers.

```
diff -rupN texstudio2.7.0-original/qcodeedit/lib/widgets/qlinenumberpanel.cpp texstudio2.7.0/qcodeedit/lib/widgets/qlinenumberpanel.cpp
--- texstudio2.7.0-original/qcodeedit/lib/widgets/qlinenumberpanel.cpp  2014-05-23 15:56:40.379727451 +0200
+++ texstudio2.7.0/qcodeedit/lib/widgets/qlinenumberpanel.cpp   2014-05-23 15:57:41.468030330 +0200
@@ -117,7 +117,9 @@ bool QLineNumberPanel::paint(QPainter *p
*/

    QFont f(font());
-   f.setWeight(QFont::Bold);
+   //f.setWeight(QFont::Bold);
+   f.setPointSize(f.pointSize()-4);
+   p->setFont(f);
    const QFontMetrics sfm(f);
    bool specialFontUsage=false;
    QFont specialFont(font());
@@ -141,8 +143,9 @@ bool QLineNumberPanel::paint(QPainter *p
    specialFontUsage=true;
#endif

-   int max = e->document()->lines();
-   if(max<100) max=100; // always reserve 3 line number columns to avoid ugly jumping of width
+   //int max = e->document()->lines();
+   //if(max<100) max=100; // always reserve 3 line number columns to avoid ugly jumping of width
+   int max = 100;
    QString s_width=QString::number(max);
    s_width.fill('6');
    const int panelWidth = sfm.width(s_width) + 5;
@@ -182,7 +185,7 @@ bool QLineNumberPanel::paint(QPainter *p
            draw = !((n + 1) % 10) || !n || !line.marks().empty();
        }

-       txt = QString::number(n + 1);
+       txt = QString::number((n + 1) % 1000);

    if ( n == cursorLine )
    {
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I also tried a lot of tricks to acheive the same. And I found a way ... I am using TeXstudio 2.12.16

1. create a file `stylesheet.qss` in your settings directory. In my Ubuntu, it is `~/.config/texstudio/`.
2. Put the following in that file `QLineNumberPanel, QLineNumberPanel *  { color : #000; font-size: 9px;}`. These are my settings, you may choose whatever suits you.

Let me know if it works. It is not perfect and many things do not follow the intuitive way on changing other things.

Comment: This kind of works. It changes the font size of the line numbers but not the column width.